# Bootrstrap Event in a "for cycle"

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, bootstrap-4

i have a web portal that reads a MYSQL database and creates a row for each data found.
In each of those rows there is a toggle button that should do one thing if it is checked, and something else if it is not.

I have it working but only for the first row. How do I get it to work for all rows?

````
<tbody>
    <?php 
    if(count($userData)>0){
        $s  =   '';
        foreach($userData as $val){
            $s++;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $s;?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $val['rep_id'];?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $val['rep_alias'];?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $val['rep_email'];?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $val['rep_phone'];?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $val['rep_role'];?></td>
        <td>
            <?php $val['rep_role'];
                if($val['rep_role']!="DISABILITATO"){
                    ?>
                    <div class="checkbox text-center">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="inServizio" id="inServizio" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="SI" data-off="NO" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
                    </div>
                    <div id="console-event"></div>
                    <!--<input type="hidden" name="hidden_inServizio" id="hidden_inServizio" value="NO" />-->
            </td>
            <?php 
                }?>
        <td align="center"><?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($val['dt']));?></td>
        <td align="center">
            <a href="edit_rep.php?editId=<?php echo $val['id'];?>" class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Modifica</a> | 
            <a href="delete_rep.php?delId=<?php echo $val['id'];?>" class="text-danger" onClick="return confirm('Sei sicuro di vole cancellare il Negozio?');"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i> Elimina</a>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <?php 
        }
    }else{
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center col-md-auto">Nessun Dato trovato!!</td>
        <td class="text-center col-md-auto">Nessun Dato trovato!!</td>
        <td class="text-center col-md-auto">Nessun Dato trovato!!</td>
        <td class="text-center col-md-auto">Nessun Dato trovato!!</td>
        <td class="text-center col-md-auto">Nessun Dato trovato!!</td>
        <td class="text-center col-md-auto">Nessun Dato trovato!!</td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>     


$(function() {
    $('#inServizio').change(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            $('#console-event').html('Stato: ON' );
        } else {
            $('#console-event').html('Stato: OFF ');
        }
        $(this).prop('checked')
    })
}); ```
````

Comment: You are using an ID selector.  Valid HTML only allows an id to be used once. Try using a class if you want to have multiple items.

Comment: Thank for reply. Could you show me how you ll solve my problem? I need examples because I am Newby and need to improve. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the id "inServizio" to put a listener. But this id just affect one element in the DOM (in the first), because with id we just identify one in all the document.

Here a solution of many:

1. In the element (HTML):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inServizio" class="inServizio" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="SI" data-off="NO" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
```

2. Javascript

```
$('.inServizio').change(function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
       $(this).parent().siblings().html('Stato: ON' );
    } else {
       $(this).parent().siblings().html('Stato: OFF ');
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks in advance for reply. I 've edited code like you suggested me but nothing happens. Now neither on first line appears "STATO: ON or OFF.
How can i check it? or troubleshooting it?
regards

Comment: It works!!! I mean, where not working this part "$(this).parent().siblings().html('Stato: ON' );" but putting in it "console.log" i saw change function works!! Thank you very much